# How to add children nodes to the last parent node

Tags: java, nodes, jtree

i wanna add some children nodes to the last parent node but here I don't work with variables to add nodes and this is my code for more details

Code :

```
Table table = new Table();
    XMLTable xtable = new XMLTable();

    File[] files = null; 
    File projectsDirectory = new File("projects");
    files = projectsDirectory.listFiles();
    for( File f : files){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(f.getName()));// parent node added
            for(File fc : f.listFiles()){

                if(fc.isFile() && fc.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("table.xml")){

                    table = xtable.getXMLTable("table.xml");
                    ArrayList<Column> cols = table.getColumns();
                    for(Column col:cols){
                        ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) f.getName()).add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(col.getName()));//don't work (just for test)
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be shooting yourself in the foot by creating your TreeNodes inline, within the `add(...)` method, since you end up with no viable reference to use later in your code. So instead, don't create your tree node objects in-line, but instead, within your for loop, create a TreeNode variable, assign it the object, add it to the root, and then use the local variable to add more nodes if need be.

e.g.,

```
Table table = new Table();
XMLTable xtable = new XMLTable();

File[] files = null; 
File projectsDirectory = new File("projects");
files = projectsDirectory.listFiles();
for( File f : files){
    if(f.isDirectory()){
        TreeNode treeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(f.getName());
        root.add(treeNode);// parent node added
        for(File fc : f.listFiles()){

            if(fc.isFile() && fc.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("table.xml")){

                table = xtable.getXMLTable("table.xml");
                ArrayList<Column> cols = table.getColumns();
                for(Column col:cols){
                    treeNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(col.getName()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```